Why is my matplotlib boxplot completely blank?
I have a pandas dataframe named 'target', with the following structure:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
RangeIndex: 200000 entries, 0 to 199999
Data columns (total 1 columns):        
 #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype
---  ------  --------------   -----
 0   0       200000 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)

I want to create a boxplot of the data in this dataframe and save it to file. My code looks like this:
boxplot = target.boxplot()
boxplot.plot()
plt.savefig('Boxplot.png')
plt.clf()

The resulting png is completely blank - no data, no axis, no title, just a blank white rectangle.
If I use plt.show() instead to try and see what's being plotted, nothing happens; no popup is generated, not even a blank one.
Does anyone know what might be causing this problem please?
EDIT: I've discovered something odd - creating a histogram of the same data first causes plt.show() to work. However, saving still results in a blank png.
In other words, the following code shows the histogram and the boxplot as popups correctly. However, it saves both as blank pngs:
histogram = target.hist()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Histogram.png')
plt.clf()

boxplot = target.boxplot()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Boxplot.png')
plt.clf()


target.boxplot() creates the boxplot. Why are you calling boxplot.plot()?

@JohanC I tried defining target as per your example, but I get the same result - the png generated is just a blank white rectangle. I don't get any error messages when running this or my original code.

@BigBen Sorry, I should have been clearer! I added boxplot.plot() after the first blank png was generated, because I thought the problem might be that the code was creating a plot but not actually plotting any data to it. However, I get the same result whether boxplot.plot() is included or not.

As described in the pyplot.show() documentation: "At the end of (a blocking) show() the figure is closed and thus unregistered from pyplot. Calling pyplot.savefig afterwards would save a new and thus empty figure."

@MattPitkin Excellent, thanks! I swapped the code around so that plt.show comes after plt.savefig and the pngs now have data in them. Out of curiosity, do you know why the boxplot data is only generated if I generate a histogram first?

I'm afraid I've no idea why you're not seeing anything for boxplot if you don't run the hist first. I can't reproduce that as a problem and boxplot produces output as expected for me. Do you have any other matplotlib function calls in your code that you're not showing in the question?

@SRJCoding Why didn't you create a fully reproducible example from the start (including imports, test data and calls to plt.show())? There are important reasons StackOverflow insists on MREs, your post is a typical example.

@MattPitkin no, this is the only time I'm using matplotlib in this script.
